# Chef Recipe: iis_pool periodic_restart_schedule getting set to empty array

Tags: iis, chef-infra, cookbook

I am currently working on a Chef recipe where I set up an IIS application pool with a specific service account identity. However, I've observed that the periodic_restart_schedule property is being set to an empty array ([]) during each Chef run, even when I don't explicitly declare it in the recipe.
Here is a snippet of the relevant part of my recipe:

```
iis_pool app_pool_name do
  action :config
  runtime_version '4.0'
  pipeline_mode :Integrated
  identity_type :SpecificUser
  username svc_account_name
  password svc_account_password
  start_mode :AlwaysRunning 
  ignore_failure true
end
```

How to fix this? Basically, the recipe should not touch the recycling property(periodic_restart_schedule).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Chef compiles resources, it takes user defined values for properties. Any properties not defined, fall back to their defaults. So if you don't explicitly declare a value for `periodic_restart_schedule`, it will take the default, which is an empty array.

The `iis_pool` resource comes from the [iis cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/iis). And below is how the property has been defined:

```rb
property :periodic_restart_schedule, [Array, String], default: [], coerce: proc { |v| Array(v).sort }
```

So unless you specify the property in your cookbook, it will be `default: []`.

> Basically, the recipe should not touch the recycling property

I'd recommend using Chef as Configuration as Code tool (which it is), and "*manage*" the complete IIS pool with `iis_pool` resource, including `periodic_restart_schedule` and other settings, rather than running Chef to do partial configuration.

Comment: I'm seeking advice on how to handle a scenario where the periodic_restart_schedule is being modified with each Chef-client run. I attempted to declare periodic_restart_schedule explicitly, but it still changes on each run, resulting in the alteration of the PID for the w3wp process.

What would be the best approach to ensure that the recipe only checks for changes in the App Pool identity, without affecting the periodic_restart_schedule?

Comment: Do you have other code in recipe that manages the IIS instance, or is this the only block?  One option might be to run Powershell command/[script](https://docs.chef.io/resources/powershell_script/) (through Chef), and do selective configuration of the IIS Pool.

Comment: I have another recipe in Powershell that takes care of the recycling time (periodic_restart_schedule) which is working as expected, and this one is to take care of App-pool identity. is the suggestion is to convert this recipe to a powershell one which can only check for the apppool identity ?

Comment: Yes, I think the idea would be to either use Chef all the way, or Powershell all the way. In latter case, the code posted in this question would have to be converted to Powershell.